# How to Restrict User to open a existing php page?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, security

I am working on a problem where i want to restrict a user to open a PHP page
This is my javascript-

```
 <script>
      $('input[id=f1email1]').on('blur', function(){
           var k = $('input[id=f1email1]').val();
           if (k != "")
                $('span[id=showEmail]').load('emailCheck.php?email=' + k);
      });
 </script>
```

`emailCheck.php` can be accessed directly by typing into the browser and this might leak some information. I cannot even redirect the page because it connects me to database.

What can I do?

Comment: You could generate a unique request token before calling the page, and include that with the querystring, then in `emailcheck.php` ensure the given key was valid.

Comment: If viewing the page in the browser leaks sensitive information, then viewing the xhr response in your browser tools will disclose the same information. Design your application in such a way that no information the user shouldn't see is sent to the client.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan — There's nothing to stop the user extracting that token and hitting the URL with it directly.

Comment: There is if the token has a 1 request/x minutes lifespan.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan — That just means the user has to be quick.

Comment: @Quentin I agree completely, and I think your answer is the solution. Just giving the OP a possible alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference between a request made by Ajax and any other HTTP request (so you can't reliably distinguish between them, so you cannot prevent the URL from being visited directly if a user wants to visit it directly).

If the page contains information that the user shouldn't be able to get to, then don't put it in the page.

Comment: This is the best method :)

Comment: am using **AJAX** i don't want user to go to that page,just some content i wanna load in a DIV

Comment: @dissectorz — Repeating the question with parts of it being in bold isn't going to change the fact that you can't stop the user going to the URL you request if they want to.

Comment: @Quentin By any means if i Post this information by a form, and check on the page If(!isset($_POST['email'])){ **redirect**}; user can only pass value to $_GET[ ] Array Not $_POST[ ] Array what u think??

Comment: @dissectorz — For a user to make a custom POST request instead of a custom GET request is less trivial than typing a URL, but is still trivial.