# Server Side Dynamic Update Solution

Tags: php, ajax, apache

As a novice developer, I guess this is a best practice question.

I have a PHP MySql query that is included (via php include) on a page load. The output of the php is an array of data that is used to plot the points on a line chart.

I also currently have an AJAX script that refreshes the chart data, by calling the php every 60 seconds.

It all works fine. But if someone navigates to my includes folder they can run the php page. Which I don't want. When I use the below .htaccess this corrects my problem, but breaks the AJAX because it runs client side.

```
<Limit GET POST PUT>
  deny from all
  allow from 127.0.0.1
</Limit>
Options -Indexes
```

My question... is there a way to dynamically update data server side or perhaps otherwise restrict access to my includes directory so that the AJAX can still request the PHP when it needs to run?

Comment: Why? You're giving the data to the user either way. What matter if they look at it raw or after being processed by your JS?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Restrict User to open a existing php page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18189464/how-to-restrict-user-to-open-a-existing-php-page)

Comment: Good question. The chart is on a private, authenticated user dashboard page. These users can see the data. However, public users on other pages can't and shouldn't. Yet they can if they look at my includes directory. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @Quentin thanks for that link. I guess it's not possible then. Unless I add a second factor .htpasswd maybe?

Comment: That's your problem. You don't really want to restrict it to Ajax, you want to restrict it to authenticated users. Use the same authentication system that you use elsewhere.

Comment: OK, well it's a simple Wordpress page password protect. My includes folder is not within the Wordpress ecosystem. I'll have to look into it. But to be clear you are saying I could theoretically restrict access to the php files, to only those who have entered the password into the dashboard?

Comment: Yes. You're already restricting the dashboard pages. You can use the same logic.